# Data not transferred to bootstarp modal based on the value of the row

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a page which display few fields of the record. There is one button view in front of every record. When I click on the view button it opens a bootstrap modal. This modal to display the complete details of that record. Basically, i want to transfer two variable id and fy using the js. The modal is displaying  but not giving the correct output .It always show the value'1' insted of value of fy and id . what is wrong in my code.

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);
include('includes/config.php');
if(strlen($_SESSION['login'])==0)
{   
header('location:index.php');
}
else{ 

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
<meta name="description" content="" />
<meta name="author" content="" />
<!-- BOOTSTRAP CORE STYLE  -->
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<!-- MENU SECTION END-->
<div class="content-wrapper">
<div class="container">
<div class="row pad-botm">
<div class="col-md-12">
<h4 class="header-line">Manage Letter</h4>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<!-- Advanced Tables -->
<div class="panel panel-default">
<div class="panel-heading">
Outwards Letter
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">
<thead>
<tr style="text-align:center">
<th style="width:25px;">Sl.No.</th>
<th style="text-align:center">FY</th>
<th style="text-align:center">Addressee </th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$sid=$_SESSION['stdid'];
$sql="SELECT * from tbloutwards where Dep='$sid' ORDER BY id ";
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query->rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach($results as $result)
{               ?>                                     
<tr class="odd gradeX">
<td class="center"><?php echo htmlentities($cnt);?></td>
<td class="center"><?php echo htmlentities($result->fy);?></td>
<td class="center"><?php echo htmlentities($result->Dep);?></td>
<td class="center"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">View</button></t>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Modal title</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
<span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<?php
$sid=$_post['id'];
$fy=$_post['fy'];
$sql="SELECT * from tbloutwards where fy='$fy' and id='$id'  " ;
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo print_r($results['fy']);

?>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">CLOSE</button>

</td>
</tr>
<?php $cnt=$cnt+1;}}} ?>                                      
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {             
$('.open-my-modal').click(function(){
$('#id').html($(this).data('id'));
$('#fy').html($(this).data('fy'));
$('#dep').html($(this).data('dep'));

// show Modal
$('#myModal').modal('show');
});
});
</script> 
</div>
</div>
<script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<!-- BOOTSTRAP SCRIPTS  -->
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- DATATABLE SCRIPTS  -->
<script src="assets/js/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/dataTables/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<!-- CUSTOM SCRIPTS  -->
<script src="assets/js/custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace PDO::FETCH_OBJ to PDO::FETCH_ASSOC and fetchAll to fetch:

```
$sid=$_post['id'];
$fy=$_post['fy'];
$sql="SELECT * from tbloutwards where fy='$fy' and id='$id'  " ;
$query = $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$results=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo print_r($results['fy']);
```

Only then will the $results contain an associative array, in which there will be a key 'fy'.